# How can I delete a vimscript function?

Tags: vimscript

I have a function that I would like to run once and do nothing in subsequent calls to it. It handles lazy-loading of plugins.

```
function! LoadExpensivePlugins()
  call StuffToRunOnceOnly
  " what do i do here?
endfun
```

Comment: Trying to define a new function inside of it results in `E127: Cannot redefine function LoadExpensivePlugins: It is in use`

Comment: I would simply delete it: `:delfunction` (this won't work from within the function however (as you noted))

Comment: couldn't find `:delfunction`. Thank you....

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for trying to postpone the loading of plugins? I would say that the features of a plugin that you do not need all the time should not be loaded until they are needed. Vim provides ways of doing just that with autoload and ftplugin etc.

Comment: YouCompleteMe is the main one that is big and expensive. I use Vim-Plug to manage the plugins. My understanding of the situation is that vim-plug and vim's own auto/on-demand loading do not work properly on this plugin so I'm using [this](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/faq#loading-plugins-manually) technique, but since it's getting more unwieldy, I'm breaking it out to its own function.

Comment: As for why bother attempting on-demand/lazy loading of plugins, even though it seems difficult to push vim startup time below 500ms, it's much better than the ~1200ms startup time I had before when everything always gets loaded. The other main thing is that a YCM daemon chews RAM like delicious candy. If I'm only opening a file to view it to make it visible in my terminal, I do not need it. So I want it set up so it gets loaded upon entering insert mode or upon using a related command such as Go to definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is simply to set a variable:

```
let s:LoadExpensivePluginsHasBeenRun = 0
function! LoadExpensivePlugins()
   if !(s:LoadExpensivePluginsHasBeenRun)
      call StuffToRunOnceOnly
      let s:LoadExpensivePluginsHasBeenRun = 1
   endif
endfun
```

Comment: Also would accept `:delfunction` as an answer, it seems more directly answering my original question.